# Suspended from chat without warning

Tags: support, flagging, chat, ban

As I've been trying out something I have suggested in my own post [here](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5611/32231), I found myself suspended from the chat already.

Yes, I did flag messages of a specific user a few times, I believe they were legit though, however is it normal to suspend without giving a warning?

If I would have been given a warning, then I would have stopped flagging and instead would have watched how another new drama could have unfolded in *The 2nd Monitor*, what's more, this suspension is sitewide, so I cannot access *any* of the rooms I participate in right now.

If this behavior continues then I won't see myself flagging things in chat anymore that are not 100% offensive, as I'm not wanting to get suspended obviously. If nobody will flag disputable content anymore, then I don't see how we can keep *The 2nd Monitor* alive, as obviously something needs to be done to keep it from melting down, as we are discussing [here](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5606/how-much-idle-chatter-do-we-tolerate-in-the-2nd-monitor).

---

Just now seeing @Jamal's message [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22506080#22506080) I realized that flagging is meant for **deleting** the chat message rather than notifying that a chat message is annoying/disputable/etc. A warning would have sufficed.

Comment: soo... what of this post then??

Comment: @Vogel612 There is a question in this post.

Comment: maybe not a full answer, but Jamal had to repeat that multiple times in multiple rooms

Answer (score 5):

Chat is a privilege, not a right. It is a system in place for the civil discussion of whatever the topic is for the chat room (as long as it fits in the general "be nice policy" too).

You were repeatedly flagging a specific user's posts as spam/offensive, and the posts were not. This is considered to be flag abuse.

Sure, you could have been warned, which may have been nice, I guess, but a warning just leads to a discussion about what's OK, and what's not OK. At the time, that would not have been a reasonable course of action.

I would have reacted in a similar way to Jamal (except I probably would have named you in the chat message: *I just suspended @skiwi for repeatedly flagging things in an inappropriate way* ).

Chat is a hard place to moderate (see my proposed nomination question) and it is a fast-moving, volatile process.

As a moderator, you act decisively, and and a 60 minute suspension is about right. Give the moderator and the chat room time to get a breath, and you too.

It's a suspension, short, so deal with it, and move on.

Comment: Just to be clear, trolling users are not considered to be offensive?

Comment: @Mast - and that's exactly why you don't warn people before suspending them - someone opens it up as a new area to discuss, which is a good trolling strategy

Comment: @Mast correct. as long as they aren't spouting insults all around. the "correct" way to deal with them is putting them on your ignore list